# Remove postgresql service from systemctl after upgrade

Tags: debian, upgrade, systemctl

After upgrading Postgresql version on Debian, I noticed that the old version of postgres continues to appear.

```
$ systemctl | grep postgresql

postgresql@oldversion-main.service    loaded failed failed     PostgreSQL Cluster oldversion-main

postgresql@newversion-main.service    loaded active running      PostgreSQL Cluster newversion-main
```

How can I remove "oldversion"?

PS. I've already removed "oldversion" using `apt-get remove`

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `apt-get purge ...` ?

Comment: @farax, hi, yes I did that but it seems that ortegaga had the right answer here regarding systemctl. Thanks again for your answer too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced the same problem after upgrading from 9.4 to 9.6 from jessie-backports. You only have to reset the failed state of the 9.4 cluster:

```
# systemctl reset-failed
```

Answer (score 3):

First backup your databases.

Next list installed versions:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
# results
...
ii  postgresql-9.5    9.5.6-1.pgdg80+1  amd64 object-relational SQL database...
...
```

remove old version

```
apt-get remove postgresql-9.5

# or remove including data and configuration
apt-get purge postgresql-9.5
```